# rspec testing for url parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails

I need some help in writing some rpsec tests for receiving paramters from a url.
The url  generated from the view looks likes

```
localhost:3000/tests/?my_id=2
```

My controller is just receiving the parameters.

```
@my_id = params[:my_id]
```

I would probably need to test whether a parameter was passed and if so whether it is an integer.
Should I test that in my controller or should I test in my rspec.

I dont need to test it if ?my_id was not passed passed.(localhost:3000/tests/)
I havent written much unit tests. If someone could point me to the correct direction that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you choose do it in your controller, you can check it and validate with a spec for the controller output.
If you choose to write a spec, it can be done too. But it won't be nice.

My advise for you is to make it in your controller and validate the controller output with a spec. Writing specs for controller is only to validate the output data, not a business thing.

Comment: thanks..it would be helpful if you could provide me with an example or a link to validate the controller output with a spec in my situation. thanks